# Хочу использовать states в aiogram выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton,InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

class DataInput(StatesGroup):
    kb = State()

bot = Bot(token="token")#Здесь мой токен
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_hello(message: types.Message):
      await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет\nЧто будем делать?')
      await DataInput.kb.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=DataInput.kb)
async def put_registration_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    kb_text = message.text
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, kb_text)
    await state.finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=True)
```

**ошибка:**

```
C:\Users\Hayk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "C:/Users/Hayk/Desktop/Pycharm/pycharm/heroku/async question bot/make_question_bot.py"
C:\Users\Hayk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\filters\state.py:57: FSMStorageWarning: You haven’t set any storage yet so no states and no data will be saved. 
You can connect MemoryStorage for debug purposes or non-essential data.
  await state.set_state(self.state)
```

Comment: Во-первых, это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Во-вторых, в предупреждении ясно описана проблема. Вы не смогли скопировать строку "You haven’t set any storage yet so no states and no data will be saved." в Google Translate?

Comment: Скопировал смотрел, но не разобрался поэтому и здесь пишу )
Спасибо

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

...

dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
```